# XElement.Parse NotSuportedException

Tags: c#, xml, exception, linq-to-xml

I get a NotSupportedException when I parse the following string with an XElement:

```
<ref>S. L. Vartanyan*, V. E. Garutt† & A. V. Sher‡parallel, "Holocene dwarf mammoths from Wrangel Island in the Siberian Arctic", Nature 362, 337&nbsp;– 340 (25 March 1993) [http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v362/n6418/abs/362337a0.html Nature.com]</ref>
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the `&nbsp;` - that isn't an xml entity unless you are in html, and also the `&` should be `&amp;`?

Basically, that isn't xml...

This works:

```
@"<ref>S. L. Vartanyan*, V. E. Garutt† &amp; A. V. Sher‡parallel, ""Holocene dwarf mammoths from Wrangel Island in the Siberian Arctic"", Nature 362, 337not-nbsp;– 340 (25 March 1993) [http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v362/n6418/abs/362337a0.html Nature.com]</ref>");
```

Comment: @Razvi - it would be better to start with xml ;p

Comment: It's a reference from a raw wikipedia page ... thought i could use XElement to get the ref's name attribute's value and content. I wrote the parsing of the ref without XElement in the end :).

Comment: @Razvi in *that* case, maybe the "HTML Agility Pack" would have solved this for you? It is much more forgiving than the strict xml parsers.